# NRF24L01 and arduino does not communicate correctly

Tags: networking, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to exchange data between 2 Atmega328P through NRF24L01.

1) Library and Sketch
I use the Tmh20 library [here](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/) . And use the getting started sketch to start [here](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24/tree/master/examples/GettingStarted) .

I send to the first arduino witht the code bool radioNumber = 0;
and the second bool radioNumber = 1;

But i am getting nothing ( just 5 weird character on the Serial console).

2) Schema and electronic

This is an image of the schematic [image]
 and this is a picture of what i have on the breadboard [image]

```
Also i plug 
CE -> D7
CSN -> D8
SCK -> D13
MOSI ->D11
MISO ->D12
```

I add a 10 micro farad capacitor between the GND and VCC of the NRF24L01.

My voltage supply come from a power generator ( current consomption is 0.6 A for the two arduino with 2 NRF24L01 ). The power supply provide 5 V and i derive 3.3 V using an LM3940 using the first schema (simplied ) on the datasheet here

3) Symptom

Nothing appear on the Serial console except 5 weird characters.I can't see any light for activity on the NRF24 module.

If anyone have an idea about i could debug that thing ?

All the best

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see anything from what is written from the setup part of the code:

```
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println(F("RF24/examples/GettingStarted"));
Serial.println(F("*** PRESS 'T' to begin transmitting to the other node"));
```

it will probably be related to other things than the NRF communication itself. Have you remembered to set the baud rate in your serial monitor to 115200 baud?
Mismatch in baudrates are a common cause of weird characters shown in Serial Monitor.

Best regards,
Bjorn Erik

Comment: Thanks ! it help me with the weird character,so now i have another issue,i use the [link](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24/tree/master/examples/pingpair_ack) , to test,but i receive a lot of "send failed" then it worked for a bit ( but with really long round-time like half a second then it go crazy til 10 s. Then stop working it look completly random

Comment: I had a lot if similar problems earlier due to the fact that the common libraries powered down the tranceivers after every transmit... A guy called Freg Copeland forked the RF24 library and fixed the PowerDown issue. After that my code has been running stable on at least my devices. Here is a link to the forked RF24 library: https://github.com/gcopeland/RF24. -BE

Comment: Thanks i think that was it i am getting better result,however i am still having strange behavior.I use the pingpair exemple and the latency increase as the time go ( see the picture [here](http://s12.postimg.org/g24g5fcrx/Roun_Trip_RF24.png)